# Accessing Computers/Devices on a Network from Linux

Tags: linux, network-shares, home-networking

I have a network hard drive that I want to access from my Linux system as well as some other computers that run Windows, but I have no idea how to go about doing this. The desktop environment Gnome has a "Browse Network" option, but it doesn't do anything at the moment. I've heard of NFS and Samba, but I'm having difficulties understanding how I'm supposed to configure them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the drive is already accessible from Windows, then it most likely uses SMB, not NFS. To enable SMB (Samba) support in GNOME, make sure you have *`gvfs-smb`*, *`gvfs-backends`* or similar package installed. This *should* be enough to allow browsing the network.

If you know the drive's IP address, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in the file manager, then enter `smb://address` next to *Location*.

To access it by *name*, you might need `libnss_wins.so`, which usually comes as part of *`samba`* or *`winbind`* packages. Once you have it, edit the "`hosts:`" line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`; add "`wins`" as the last item. Some distributions will do it for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can just view all the available computers/devices instead of having to enter the address or name?

Comment: Sorry, I should have searched myself before asking. The trick is to install *smbnetfs*. The workgroup should be mounted under `/mnt/smbnet` after starting the daemon.

Comment: @someguy: I did say that installing the apropriate Gvfs backend should be enough to enable network browsing in GNOME.

Comment: There is no *gvfs-backends* package for my system (Arch) or anything similar that installs *smbnetfs*.

Comment: @someguy: There is `gvfs-smb`, though. (I don't recommend using smbnetfs, but you can dig into the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=19208) and hope the old package still works.)

Comment: That doesn't allow me to view all the computers. I have to enter the address or name. Also, what's wrong with smbnetfs? Edit: Sorry, I get it now. I have to type *smb://workgroup*. Thank you :p.

Comment: @someguy: Ah, I forgot the workgroup. GNOME used to have a place to set the workgroup per-user; currently you have to dig into `dconf` for it. (Or set it system-wide at `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.) I don't have anything against smbnetfs myself, but I tend to avoid old and unmaintained software when an active alternative (Gvfs) is available.